# Spring accepting data from form getting 404 error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model, spring-data

I am trying to take an input from a form made in a jsp called "start.jsp".

```
<body>
 <form action=/addResults"method="post" modelAttribute="results" required="true">
 <label for="email">Email Address:</label><br>
 <input type="text" id="email" name="email" maxlength="50"required><br>
  <label for="fullname">Full Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" maxlength="100"required>
  <label for="age">Age (0-120):</label><br>
 <input type="text" id="age" name="age" min="0" max="120"required>
 <label for="gender">Gender:</label><br>
 <input type="text" id="gender" name="gender" maxlength="45"required>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form> 
  </p>
  </body>
```

I'm then using code in my Controller to add this to a Class. Below is my controller code.

```
    @RequestMapping("/addResults")
    public String newHotel(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("results", new TestResults());
    return "start";
 }
```

But when I execute my Spring project it gives me an error of 404-not found. I've tried checking and rechecking my links and I can't understand how the links can't find the other pages etc. Any help would very great as I'm quite new to spring and the franework. Fred

Comment: Could you please confirm that  your Spring Boot application is running and that you can access you resource with browse of post man?

Comment: A naive question: Shouldn't it be RequestMapping("addResults")`?

Comment: Hello sorry about the wait, I have tried using ("addResults") and that still doesn't work. I don't quite understand the first question but the spring boot app runs successfully until I send data in the form